# Calculating columns in a listview

Tags: c#, listview

I am new to programming and I have a price list in a list view, I would like to have another column that calculates the last column and a textbox together, please point me in the right direction as I am getting method and format errors.. here is my code:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:xxxx;Persist Security Info=False");
OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

if (comboBox1.Text == "Brickcom")
{
    ListViewItem li;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT [PartNo], [Category], [Product], [Resolution], [IncludedAccessories], [Price] FROM [Brickcom] WHERE ([Manufacturer] Like '" + comboBox1.Text.ToString() + "')";
    connection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        listView1.Columns[0].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[1].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[2].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[3].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[4].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[5].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[6].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[7].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[8].Text = null;
        listView1.Columns[0].Text = "Part Number";
        listView1.Columns[1].Text = "Category";
        listView1.Columns[2].Text = "Product";
        listView1.Columns[3].Text = "Resolution";
        listView1.Columns[4].Text = "Included Accessories";
        listView1.Columns[5].Text = "Price";
        li = listView1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        li.SubItems.Add(reader[1].ToString());
        li.SubItems.Add(reader[2].ToString());
        li.SubItems.Add(reader[3].ToString());
        li.SubItems.Add(reader[4].ToString());
        li.SubItems.Add(reader[5].ToString());

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            li.SubItems.Add(items[6].ToString());
            //listView1.Columns[6].Text = (Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
            item.SubItems[6].Text = (Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
        }

    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: Sudhakar is right. I understand that you didn't add the columns; but cannot be sure. Please, explain the exact error you are getting and in which line.

Comment: The issue is the foreach statement ... I cannot get the calculation sorted

Comment: I will explain you what your code does such that you can tell me what you want to do exactly: it goes through all the elements in the DB, renames each column every time (you should put all names outside the loop), takes the first 6 columns and adds them to the first 6 columns in the ListView and then iterate through all the rows inserted in the ListView so far, add a new column and write a certain value in each these cells -> I guess that you don't want to do that. Please, explain what you want to do.

Comment: The loop is giving me the method error if I change the item.subitems[6].value and when I change the value to text I get an format error... How do I calculate the price column and textbox into another column ? Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Please, read my previous comment properly: this loop is, most likely, not doing what you want; please, explain exactly what you want to write into the seventh column.

Comment: I made a mistake when posting my code, I was testing if I can calc two textbox's textbox2 should be the column " price ". Sorry once again.

Comment: @user3012159: what is the items array used in foreach? `items[6]`

Comment: Price column + textbox1 = into " column 6 "

Comment: @Sudhakar, sorry its testing, I forgot to remove it when posting the code... was trying something.

Comment: I have updated my answer, this is what you meant?

Comment: No, sorry! Let me try explain again. I have a price list that has 6 columns and the last column is the actual price. I have a textbox with a number that is used as a markup, this two needs to be calculated together and show the new price in a column 7. for eace row. I hope this is more clear ...

Comment: @varocarbas, any advice PLEASE ?

Comment: ?! I deleted my answer because Sudhakar answered more or less the same  and thought that was taking care of this. But he deleted his answer too?! Anyway... Your code is pretty badly structured and your problem is not clear enough. As I understand this last comment, both our answers were actually giving you the solution (?! why you keep asking and saying that the problem is somewhere else?). You have to make an effort to make yourself clear and understand the SO requirements (i.e., help to knowledgeable programmers which might be used by other people).

Comment: Perhaps the best links (with the most reliable code) are the ones in MSDN. For example: you want to populate a listview? search for MSDN articles about ListView and start from the codes there (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx); usually, they include all the required code, so you know what you sholdn't add (e.g., Text = null). Also, an excellent way to learn is doing things by your own, not requesting help constantly (and much less whole-working codes -> this is the worst way to learn; my suggestion above is to LEARN from good codes)...

Comment: ... for example: when you find a problem; don't look at the result and come here to ask why the result is different than what I wanted? Debug (learn to debug this is extremely important and the only way to do that is just doing it) the code and find the problem. Once you find the problem, do some research for the solution; try different alternatives; and once you don't get anything, come here to ask -> this is how you should learn. This is the practical way. If you want the theoretical way (you should mix both ways, actually speaking), read theoretical stuff, internet is full of this.

Comment: I don't think that any good developer has started his learning process by asking: just trying some random commands, not understanding what he is doing and asking someone to fix it. I don't think that you need (too much) resources to become an excellent programmer; just attitude and time (logically, someone without resource does not have time but this is something which cannot be solved); and don't get distracted with what APPARENTLY seems easy and which actually is not: things are only easy for those who know how to deal with them. If you want to learn something, assume that it is difficult.